# Could not create the view: SwigDirector_CefHandler_HandleBeforeCreated

Tags: java, ubuntu, crash, aptana

Running Linux Mint 16.
Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805

Have latest Sun JDK - /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Changed /usr/bin/javaxxxx symlinks to reference JDK.

[image]

Aptana Opens normally, however,
Window -> Show View -> WebBrowser

[image]

And

Window -> Show View -> Web Browser Editor -> Crashes Aptana.

Verification that swig is installed:

[image]